# Custom payload with Laravel JWT

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 and [laravel jwt](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for token, here is the list of namespaces used by the controller.

```
use JWTAuth;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
```

I need to add custom payload data to generate the token.

Here is how i am trying to generate token with custom payloads.

```
        $payloadable = [
            'id' => $tokenPayload->id,
            'name' => $tokenPayload->name,
            'email' => $tokenPayload->email,
            'deleted_at' => $tokenPayload->deleted_at,
            'created_at' => $tokenPayload->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $tokenPayload->updated_at,
            'organization' => $request->organization_id
        ];

        // Generate the token.
        $token = JWTAuth::encode( JWTFactory::make( $payloadable ) );

        // Return token.
        return response()->json( [ 'token' => $token ] );
```

But in the response the token is empty! Here is the response

```
{
  "token": {}
}
```

Why it is returning an empty token instead of a jwt token!

**Update:**

Now i can get the token using a `\` before the `JWTFactory` namespace, but how I will be able to get the updated token value?

What I am trying to achive is to add some additional fields to an existing token, after reading Laravel JWT-auth doc, i figured out that i need to create another token which would have the additional fields but the new token is not returning additional fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try below code is working for me.

```
//load user place your code for load user
$user = User::find( $user_id );
// if you don't have user id then also you can used.
$user = User::where( 'email', $tokenPayload->email )->first();

$payloadable = [
        'id' => $tokenPayload->id,
        'name' => $tokenPayload->name,
        'email' => $tokenPayload->email,
        'deleted_at' => $tokenPayload->deleted_at,
        'created_at' => $tokenPayload->created_at,
        'updated_at' => $tokenPayload->updated_at,
        'organization' => $request->organization_id
    ];

$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user,$payloadable);
```

you can get organization using below code.

```
$payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();
// then either of
$payload->get('organization');
```

you can get new token using `fromUser` method by passing the user object.

try this code I hope this code is working for you.

[You can get more detail from here](https://thecodingstuff.com/2017/10/04/how-to-set-custom-payload-on-laravel-jwt/).

Comment: Only user information's are available with this method no other fields :(

Comment: You have user id?

Comment: Yes, i have the user id

Comment: then you can easily load user inform from database using user model like  `User::find( $user_id )`

Comment: But i need to add custom fields as payload.

Comment: You want to pass your custom fields i update my answer please check if it is help full for you. also you can pass your custom claims to `JWTAuth::fromUser` function. or remove unused data from array and add only `payloadable` all other data you can get it from user object.

Comment: Everything works but the added field "organization" is not in the token

Comment: I update my answer please try that code for getting `organization` value.

Answer (score 8):

The way I add custom payload in my controller:

```
    $customClaims = ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bob'];
    $token = JWTAuth::claims($customClaims)->attempt($credentials);
```

The way I get back my custom payload:

```
    dd(auth()->payload()->get('foo'));
```

Answer (score 5):

This solution was tested on **tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0**

```
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory;

//...

$user = User::find(1);

$payload = JWTFactory::sub($user->id)
    ->myCustomString('Foo Bar')
    ->myCustomArray(['Apples', 'Oranges'])
    ->myCustomObject($user)
    ->make();

$token = JWTAuth::encode($payload);

return response()->json(['token' => $token]);
```

The code above will return a token that represents:

```
{
    "iss": "http://yourdomain.com", //Automatically inserted
    "iat": 1592808100,              //Automatically inserted
    "exp": 1592811700,              //Automatically inserted
    "nbf": 1592808100,              //Automatically inserted
    "jti": "wIyXAEvPk64nyH3C"       //Automatically inserted
    "sub": 1,                       //User ID (required)
    "myCustomString": "Foo Bar",
    "myCustomArray":  ["Apples", "Oranges"],
    "myCustomObject": { ... } //Full $user object
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You return the $token, but use $token->get() instead.

```
return response()->json(['token' => $token->get()]);
```

This should call the __toString().

Comment: Error: Call to a member function get() on string

Comment: $token should be instance of  `Tymon\JWTAuth\Token`

Answer (score 0):

If your are using jwt in login. 
Why don't you try `$customClaims` in attempt when login. the attempt will take care everything else to generate the token.

```
JWTAuth::attempt(array $credentials = [], array $customClaims = [])
```

Comment: Why the token is not returning other fields?

Answer (score 0):

i am creating token using encode only, have same problem, so i just change the created token's type to string worked.

```
return response()->json( [ 'token' => (string) $token ] );
```